# python append not adding to list

Tags: python, arraylist

I am trying to learn python and am currently working with a basic dice roll script.
2 die roll until they both hit 6. when it will print the number of rolls it took to hit the defined [6:6].

this repeats 2 more times as seen with

```
for x in range(3):
        roll_dice()
```

My problem is that when I try to sum the *run* list it will only print the last dice roll count. I'm thinking my `run.append(count)` is not updating but resetting once it goes through the loop again?

I understand the rest of my code is probably really inefficient but still early stages of learning.

```
import random

def roll_dice():
    dice_one = 0
    dice_two = 0
    count = 0
    run = []
    while True:
        dice_one = random.randrange(1,7)
        dice_two = random.randrange(1,7)
        count += 1
        print(dice_one, " ", dice_two)

        if dice_one +  dice_two == 12:
            print("----", count, "attempts----")
            break
    run.append(count)
    print(sum(run))

for x in range(3):
        roll_dice()
```

Comment: I just love the indentation =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put `run.append(count)` in the while loop:

```
import random

def roll_dice():
    dice_one = 0
    dice_two = 0
    count = 0
    run = []
    while True:
        dice_one = random.randrange(1,7)
        dice_two = random.randrange(1,7)
        count += 1
        print(dice_one, " ", dice_two)

        if dice_one +  dice_two == 12:
            print("----", count, "attempts----")
            break
        run.append(count)
    print(sum(run))

for x in range(3):
        roll_dice()
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the others have pointed out, the `run.append(count)` is being called outside the `While` loop. Due to this, only the last updated value of count is being added to run.
By moving the `run.append(count)` inside the `While` loop, it will be updated each time the loop is executed.

Answer (score 0):

`print(sum(run))` only prints the last dice roll count because `run.append(count)` is outside the while loop. It is only called once on every function call. Put it inside the while loop and it will append each time you roll the dies.